# Match on value within string than contains space

Tags: java, regex

Using the below regex's I'm attempting to extract a string value that is contained in double quotes and print the values to screen. This works as expected for the string `e,r,t,"$0 = test1 $1 = test2 $5 = test3 ",a,b,c,d` and regex pattern `"\" *\\$\\p{Alnum}+ *= *\\p{Alnum}+ *(?:, *\\$\\p{Alnum}+ *= *\\p{Alnum}+ *)*(, )?\""` producing :

```
0->test1
1->test2
5->test3
```

If I indroduce a space to one of the values ($1 = test 2): `"e,r,t,\"$0 = test1\n$1 = test 2\n$5 = test3\n\",a,b,c,d"` then the pattern fails to match.
So I update to use a new regex : `"\" *\\$\\p{Alnum}+ *= *\\p{Alnum}| + *(?:, *\\$\\p{Alnum}+ *= *\\p{Alnum}| + *)*(, )?\""`

The update regex include an "or space" `|`

This partially matches as the following is produced :

```
0->t
```

src:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ReadLine2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        final String st = "e,r,t,\"$0 = test1\n$1 = test 2\n$5 = test3\n\",a,b,c,d";
        //final String st = "e,r,t,\"$0 = test1\n$1 = test2\n$5 = test3\n\",a,b,c,d";

        final Pattern quotesPattern = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\"", Pattern.DOTALL);
        final Matcher quotesMatcher = quotesPattern.matcher(st);
        quotesMatcher.find();
        String mv = quotesMatcher.group(0).replace("\n", ", ");
        System.out.println("mv : " + mv);

        final Map<String, String> mappedValues = new HashMap<String, String>();

        final Pattern find = Pattern.compile("\" *\\$\\p{Alnum}+ *= *\\p{Alnum}| + *(?:, *\\$\\p{Alnum}+ *= *\\p{Alnum}| + *)*(, )?\"");
        //final Pattern find = Pattern.compile("\" *\\$\\p{Alnum}+ *= *\\p{Alnum}+ *(?:, *\\$\\p{Alnum}+ *= *\\p{Alnum}+ *)*(, )?\"");
        final Pattern extract = Pattern.compile("\\$(\\p{Alnum}+) *= *(\\p{Alnum}+)");

        final Matcher matcher = find.matcher(mv);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            final Matcher extractor2 = extract.matcher(matcher.group(0));
            while (extractor2.find())
                System.out.println(extractor2.group(1) +"->"+extractor2.group(2));
        }
    }

}
```

produces :

```
mv : "$0 = test1, $1 = test 2, $5 = test3, "
0->t
```

How to modify the regex such that spaces keys values with spaces such as "test 2" are matched.

For a string `"e,r,t,\"$0 = test1\n$1 = test 2\n$5 = test3\n\",a,b,c,d"`

I'm attempting to produce the following :

```
0->test1
1->test 2
5->test3
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  `"\" *\\$\\p{Alnum}+ *=[\\s\\p{Alnum}]+(?:,\\s*\\$[\\p{Alnum}\\s]+=[\\s\\p{Alnum}]+)*(,\\s)?\""` returns `0->test1
1->test
5->test3` .

`1->test` should be `1->test 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the alternation character `|`, you need to group the alternatives, so `\\p{Alnum}| +` would be `(?:\\p{Alnum}| )+`. Or you could use a character set `[ \\p{Alnum}]+`.

Here is a simple example that produces the required result. I have omitted the rest of your regex and other code for simplicity and clarity's sake.

```java
String text = "e,r,t,\"$0 = test1\n$1 = test 2\n$5 = test3\n\",a,b,c,d";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{Alnum}+ *=(?: *\\p{Alnum}+)+");
        
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}

//  0 = test1
//  1 = test 2
//  5 = test3
```

The pattern `(?: *\\p{Alnum}+)+` matches zero or more space characters followed by one or more alphanumeric characters, and does this one or more times. I used this pattern to ensure that the value matched ends with an alphanumeric character rather than trailing space.

If you know you are always matching up to a newline and you are not trying to validate the value following the `=`, then as long as you are not using `Pattern.DOTALL`, you could simply use:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{Alnum}+ *=.+");
```